# How can I speed up Mathematica calculations?

Tags: performance-tuning, prime-numbers, version-11

I am using Mathematica 11.1 to deterministically test the primality of a set of very large numbers (i.e. more than 1000 digits). Some of these calculations (understandably) take a lot of time (several days). I have purchased the Home/Hobby version of Mathematica, which allows the parallel use of 4 kernels.

I don't have the money to upgrade to a several-thousand-dollar version of the software, which would be able to use more kernels, so how do I make the most out of my current version? Are there ways to tweak the settings so that I can increase the speed of my computations?

The function I am using currently is *ProvablePrimeQ*, but the question remains valid for any other computationally expensive operation.

**EDIT** I am *only* using the function *ProvablePrimeQ* on large probable prime numbers. There is no script, no "code", just the single function.

Comment: Please supply the code you have tried and a specific test case that illustrates the problem.  Easier to get responses and useful answers.

Comment: @Pickle, how do you generate primes? How large is the set? Why set?

Comment: @garej The word "set" is used very freely here, it's simply a better way to say "a number of numbers". These numbers are not related in any way, except that they are all "probable" primes. They are of interest only if they are proved to be prime. Hence the deterministic prime test.